# SQL 2005 : Master,modal,msdb,tempdb

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have question regarding sql system database that what purpose of these database of msdb and msdb.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=master+model+msdb+tempdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check MSdn : System Databases and Data : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174522%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Microsoft® SQL Server™ 2000 systems have four system databases:

```
* master

  The master database records all of the system level information for a SQL Server system. It records all login accounts and all system configuration settings. master is the database that records the existence of all other databases, including the location of the database files. master records the initialization information for SQL Server; always have a recent backup of master available.
* tempdb

  tempdb holds all temporary tables and temporary stored procedures. It also fills any other temporary storage needs such as work tables generated by SQL Server. tempdb is a global resource; the temporary tables and stored procedures for all users connected to the system are stored there. tempdb is re-created every time SQL Server is started so the system starts with a clean copy of the database. Because temporary tables and stored procedures are dropped automatically on disconnect, and no connections are active when the system is shut down, there is never anything in tempdb to be saved from one session of SQL Server to another.

  By default, tempdb autogrows as needed while SQL Server is running. Unlike other databases, however, it is reset to its initial size each time the database engine is started. If the size defined for tempdb is small, part of your system processing load may be taken up with autogrowing tempdb to the size needed to support your workload each time to restart SQL Server. You can avoid this overhead by using ALTER DATABASE to increase the size of tempdb.
* model

  The model database is used as the template for all databases created on a system. When a CREATE DATABASE statement is issued, the first part of the database is created by copying in the contents of the model database, then the remainder of the new database is filled with empty pages. Because tempdb is created every time SQL Server is started, the model database must always exist on a SQL Server system.
* msdb

  The msdb database is used by SQL Server Agent for scheduling alerts and jobs, and recording operators.
```